# issue with jqGrid,acting as dialog modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I have design the jqGrid, jqGrid is showing as Modal popup with warning sign
why is it doing so? i don't want it as Modal dialog. Screen shot is attached 
Any help is appreciated

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

and

```
$(function () {
    jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid({
        data: POnbrsDetails,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ['PO_NBR', 'FY', 'LN', 'FOA', 'PROJ_ID', 'SCR_TPY', 'Encum_Amt', 'Paid', 'Balance'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'PO_Nbr', index: 'PO_Nbr', width: 100, align: "center", },
            { name: 'FY', index: 'FY', width: 100, align: "left" },
            { name: 'LN', index: 'LN', width: 100, align: "center" },
            { name: 'FOA', index: 'FOA', width: 120, align: "right" },
            { name: 'PROJ_ID', index: 'Proj_ID', width: 100, align: "center" },
            { name: 'SCR_Type', index: 'Srce_Type', width: 100 },
            { name: 'Encum_Amt', index: 'Encum_Amt', width: 100, align: "center", summaryType: 'sum' },
            { name: 'Paid', index: 'Paid', width: 100, summaryType: 'sum' },
            { name: 'Balance', index: 'Balance', width: 100, summaryType: 'sum' }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        height: 'auto',
        pager: '#pager',                
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "SWIFT NSME",
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['PO_Nbr'],
            groupColumnShow: [true],
            groupCollapse: false,
            groupSummary: [true],
            showSummaryOnHide: true,
            groupDataSorted: true,                  
        },
        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true
    });
    jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
});
```

and

```
<table id="grid2"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very unclear. You wrote about **"Modal popup with warning sign"**. Which modal popup you mean? The picture which you included contains no "warning sign". What is your problem? Moreover it's important to write **which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use**?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed some more information to give some options. When the warning popup will open? Where is the popup initialization in the jquery code? Have you initialized the popup ? Where is the popup html block ? At which condition the warning popup will open?